# Python3 + Tweepy streaming ERROR

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, tweepy

I would like to print out tweets which have #Berlin hashtag in it. How can I rewrite the code?I cant find sample codes in python3 for this action. 
I have the following problem:

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

    consumer_key = ''
    consumer_secret = ''
    access_token = ''
    access_token_secret = ''

    #This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
    class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

        def on_data(self, data):
            print (data)
            return (True)

        def on_error(self, status):
            print (status)


    if __name__ == '__main__':

        #This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
        l = StdOutListener()
        auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        stream = Stream(auth, l)

        #This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
        stream.filter(track=['Berlin'])
```

And then I got this error at the end:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    stream.filter(track=['Berlin'])
  File "/home/ubuntu/tweepy/tweepy/streaming.py", line 430, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "/home/ubuntu/tweepy/tweepy/streaming.py", line 346, in _start
    self._run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/tweepy/tweepy/streaming.py", line 286, in _run
    raise exception
  File "/home/ubuntu/tweepy/tweepy/streaming.py", line 255, in _run
    self._read_loop(resp)
  File "/home/ubuntu/tweepy/tweepy/streaming.py", line 298, in _read_loop
    line = buf.read_line().strip()
  File "/home/ubuntu/tweepy/tweepy/streaming.py", line 171, in read_line
    self._buffer += self._stream.read(self._chunk_size)
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to a known bug in tweepy [#615](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/615). Taken from a post in there.

In streaming.py:

I changed line 161 to

```
self._buffer += self._stream.read(read_len).decode('UTF-8', 'ignore')
```

and line 171 to

`self._buffer += self._stream.read(self._chunk_size).decode('UTF-8', 'ignore')`

They file you need to change on windows is located under `\Python 3.5\Lib\site-packages\tweepy`.

For Ubuntu you need: `'/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tweepy'`

Comment: I have python 3.4 and 2.7 and cant find this path.  how can I solve this problem under 2.7? @Leb

Comment: What OS you got? It shouldn't matter the python version.

Comment: I have ubuntu 14.04 desktop, anyway I found out that when I deleted the pip requests[security] (I installed it because of InsecurePlatformWarning message in python 2.7 console) seems to be working fine now.. @Leb